# How can I use parameter of Method inside the CSS Selector string?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

I have a webpage where different action buttons are available. I am identifying the action buttons using the CSS selector. I want to have a common method to click on the action buttons using the parameter of method. 
All the buttons have similar attributes but different values.

Please look into the code.

```
public static void TakeAction(WebDriver driver, String Action)
{
    WebElement btnAction= driver.findelement(By.cssSelector("input[type='button'][value='Action']").
    btnAction.click();
}
```

Now this `[value='Action'] -> Action` should be picked from the method parameter however i am not able to figure out the syntax to specify the same.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Just gave few attempts and got the syntax.

```
WebElement btnAction= driver.findelement(By.cssSelector("input[type='button'][value='"+Action+"']").
```

Comment: Yep that is what I was going to suggest. In the way you put it at first, "Action" was part of the string "input[type='button'][value='Action']", not a variable. So you have to split those parts that have to be fed using +. Well solved.